# cannot import name 'OrderedDict' from 'typing'

Tags: python, linux, typing, yolov5, ordereddict

I'm struggling to run train.py from yolov5 because of this error, I tried to search about it but nothing really helped.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 43, in <module>
    import val as validate  # for end-of-epoch mAP
  File "/home/flint/treinamento/yolov5-master/val.py", line 37, in <module>
    from models.common import DetectMultiBackend
  File "/home/flint/treinamento/yolov5-master/models/common.py", line 23, in <module>
    from utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox
  File "/home/flint/treinamento/yolov5-master/utils/dataloaders.py", line 25, in <module>
    import torchvision
  File "/home/flint/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from torchvision import datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils
  File "/home/flint/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .maxvit import *
  File "/home/flint/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/maxvit.py", line 3, in <module>
    from typing import Any, Callable, List, Optional, OrderedDict, Sequence, Tuple
ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict' from 'typing' (/home/flint/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
```

I already tried updating/changing my python version.

Comment: `typing.OrderedDict` was added to Python 3.7.2; you may have a slightly older patch level.

Comment: I tried to install python3.7 4 but it caused another error
'''Segmentation fault dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure): installed apport package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 239 Errors were encountered while processing: apport E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'''

Comment: @HannaDias this is completely different question, please consider posting it as such. The answer to this question is "your python version is not supported by the package, and you cannot resolve it without patching/forking it".

Comment: As a side note, [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) can manage your python versions without messing with your system installation. (no affiliation)

Comment: @SUTerliakov thank you, I'll post it as another question